# Impact of collecting the substance?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-defenders-2017

Why will collecting the substance result in the destruction of New York?

> The location where the substance is located doesn't seem to have any structural purpose.  It is under a dome in a big hole.  It isn't holding anything up, and doesn't seem to be impacted by a building collapsing on top if it after the dome is destroyed.

Comment: I always assumed that it would undermine the structural integrity of the ground…but that doesn’t make sense in light of Stick attributing Pompei and Chernobyl to similar activities, does it? Those were a lot more destructive than a little bit of excavation. Unless the implication is that the Hand’s excavation triggered a greater disaster in those cases, which I suppose is possible.

Comment: @Adamant And remember that the skeleton was within a dome, presumably created by a previous Iron Fist.  So even harvesting everything within the dome would have no impact on the ground above as long as the dome holds, and the implication was that the dome was virtually indestructible.  This seems a major plothole that was not addressed at all in the series.

Answer (score 1):

**Making sure no-one else can get it**

How certain the hand can be that they will mine all the available substance ?
How can they be sure that there is not a source of the substance right beyond this innocuous wall ?

By destroying the city, they ensure that no-one else can find any substance they failed to harvest/found.

Comment: Why would the Hand care if someone else found some of the substance? If anything, they could just kill those people and take what they'd found.